# What to expect when using mariadb/phpmyadmin when working with datatype 'geometry'

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, geometry, mariadb

Trying to get familiar with the datatype 'geometry', I want to import a GPX-file in a table and show it on an OSM-map. I'm using MariaDB/phpmyadmin because that's what my hoster is providing me. I'm using the 'geometry'-type because I like the ST_functions (instead of putting the lat-lon in two columns and develop/copy the needed algorithm's).

After googling and youtubing for some time now, I'm at the point that I'm wondering if I'm doing things wrong or if I'm encountering bugs. Because I don't know what to expect, I hope someone can get me on the right track.

I started on a local PC with XAMPP 7.3.4 (phpmyadmin 4.8.5/mariadb 10.1.38) installed. I started with a column datatype POINT, was surprised that phpmyadmin has the option to show the contents of a record on a map, and was dissapointed I only saw blue water. When editting a record, phpmyadmin showed a map and data which have to presented, which makes clear that SRID is '0'. Couldn't get the SRID on '4326', until some text somewhere hinted met to use a column with datatype GEOMETRY. But only a worldmap showed up.

After a lot of trying, I decided to use the hosted environment (phpmyadmin 4.9.5/mariadb 10.3.22). To my surprise the point was visible at the map. Only, on a different part of the world. Looking at the lat-lon I saw that they were interchanged. Putting them in the lon-lat sequence, the point was visible at the place where I expected it.

Because the hoster provides higher versions installed, I installed a newer XAMPP 7.4.6 (phpmyadmin 5.0.2/mariadb 10.4.1). <strike>It was a big surprise that my point wasn't showing up, just the worldmap again. So it's some configuration with the OSM-map on the local machine that needs attention?</strike> The lat-lon still have to be interchanged.

[Mapping is ok, lat-lon interchanged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgfzi.jpg)

[Mapping wrong, lat-lon ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idLeB.jpg)

Mapping of a walk in Paris. First is mapping of a GPX in Prune, second is an import of the tracked points in MariaDB. Exactly the same mapping, just had to interchange the points lat - lon. So, nothing wrong with used SRID and/or coordinates I think, just phpmysql taking the lat as y and lon as x, instead of the expected lat as x and lon as Y which puts the walk somewhere in the sea in front of Somalie:

[Mapping of walk in Paris presented in Prune](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twLRH.jpg)

[Mapping of same gps-points in phpmyadmin, lat-lon interchanged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Yw4f.jpg)

Apart from the presentation of the data, I have difficulties when using the insert-option of phpmyadmin. I only get data in one pass in the table when using sql. The insert-option generates sql which gives errors. I have to edit that sql, there are " ' "  and " \ " which I have to remove. Comparing the used versions I detected differences in number and places of the to remove " ' "and " \ ".

I looked at the phpmyadmin-issues, nothing seems open. I can find closed ones who indicate to some sort of issues I'm experiencing. A lot of docu on geo is offcourse about postgresql, some about mysql, but less about mariadb and phpmysql, it's hard to find the good directions.

So, my biggest three questions are if it's intended to store lon-lat instead of lat-lon (Or do I have to use another srid?) Second question is what I have to configure to get the map working locally like it does with my hoster (if that's what's causing the problem)? Third is if people can use the insert-option of phpmysql without editing the generated sql?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use great-circle distances, be sure to have a version of MySQL/MaraiDB that includes `st_distance_sphere`.  (I think that limits you to MySQL 8.0.)

If you are going to have code to "find the nearest", you will find that challenging.  Here's my discussion of techniques for such.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql  (Also included is a Stored Function to do great-circle calculations.)  That discusses using `SPATIAL` and other techniques.

Part of your issue is the mapping from y and x to whatever projection of the world your map has.  The spherical long-lat are thinking "sphere" not a "projection".

phpmyadmin is just a UI toop.  It *may* not be smart enough to deal with some of the SPATIAL issue.  Suggest you switch to MySQL commandline tool and/or your application code.  BTW, what language will you be writing in?

Backtics are used around table and column names.  Quotes (' or ") are used around strings.  In some contexts, backslash (`\`) may need to be doubled or even quadrupled up.

`POINT` is a 25-byte binary format.  It is best to dynamically construct the value, not spell out the value, as can be done with decimal numbers for `INT` and `FLOAT`.

And, yes, longitude comes first in `POINT()` and other `SPATIAL` thingies.

Comment: The GPX-files I want to map are my bike/run-sessions. We're not talking great-circles distances :)

Comment: I'm using (cake)php, phpmyadmin comes in handy to check the mapping of a point on a map. In this case I use the commandline tool primarily to check if my sql is working when phpmyadmin has a problem.

Comment: Added example of maps, not sure if thinking sphere or projection will give this result.

Comment: One degree of longitude at 51deg latitude is about half as long as one degree at the equator.  Since your x and y are lat and long, you do need an appropriate SRID.  For such localized work, you _could_ simply divide longitudes by cos(latitude) to get x and y values that work together.  (But they would no longer map well.)

Comment: Added walk in Paris. Really think SRID isn't the problem, also no need to get x and y values. Hope someone can confirm same or opposite result. Is x considered to be lat and y lon? Or vice versa?

Comment: @drtrppr Yes, longitude comes first in `POINT()` and other `SPATIAL` thingies.  While on the topic, some web graphics start y at the "top" of the page, with positive y values going down the page.

Comment: In that case phmyadmin is mapping the data 100%. Same conclusion in duscussion in phpmyadmin-issue https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16012